# Error when converting user input (string) to integer in dart

Tags: dart

I recently got into flutter and dart and I've been writing basic programs. Just this morning I ran into an error when trying to convert user input from a string into an integer so I could perform a mathematical operation. Here's the code.

```
import "dart:io";
import "dart:math";
import "dart:convert";

void main() {
  print("Enter a number: ");
  String num1 = stdin.readLineSync();

  print("Enter a second number");

  String num2 = stdin.readLineSync();

  print(int.parse(num1) + int.parse(num2));
}
```

Surprisingly this runs well on the online dart compiler and interpreter. (replit)

but when I run it on `vscode`, I get this error

```
"Error: A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
  String num2 = stdin.readLineSync();"
```

Whichever data type I use, I get the same error. be it `var`, or `string`, or `int` or `double`.

I tried another method of conversion but its the same thing. works on the online compiler, doesn't work on my machine. here's the code.

```
import "dart:io";
import "dart:math";
import "dart:convert";

void main() {
  print("Enter a number: ");
  var num1 = stdin.readLineSync();
  var num2 = int.parse(num1);

  print("Enter a second number");

  var num3 = stdin.readLineSync();
  var num4 = int.parse(num3);

  print(num2 + num4);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`stdin.readLineSync()` returns a `String?`. Types ending in a `?` are nullable. `String?` means either `String` or `null`.

Also `int.parse` takes a parameter of type `String` not `String?` so you cannot pass a value to it which might be `null`. There are a few different approaches you can take to work around this. One thing you can do is check if they are not `null` in an if statement, and in doing so the values of num1 and num2 will be promoted to `String` within the body of the if statement. Another approach is to use the `??` operator on num1 and num2, which is called the "if null" operator and allows you to provide a default value in the event that num1 or num2 is `null`.

```dart
import "dart:io";
import "dart:math";
import "dart:convert";

void main() {
  print("Enter a number: ");
  // set type to String? (you can also use var or final)
  String? num1 = stdin.readLineSync(); 

  print("Enter a second number");

  String? num2 = stdin.readLineSync();
  
  // check for null values before using num1 and num2
  if (num1 != null && num2 != null) {
    print(int.parse(num1) + int.parse(num2));
  }

  // alternatively you can convert the values to String 
  // using the ?? operator. if the value of num1 is null
  // then you will get '' (empty string) instead.
  print(int.parse(num1 ?? '') + int.parse(num2 ?? ''));
}
```

I am not familiar with replit, but it may be using an older version of dart language. dart version 2.12 introduced features related to null safety.

See also:

https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-12-499a6e689c87

https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety